# SSRS 2008 R2 predefined form report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report that needs to print out as a predefined form. These are government forms that must print out a full page regardless of the amount of content. I have the report created and working, just not printing a full form page. Make sense?

The report is comprised of a header with two body subreports, that currently sizes dynamically base on the content.

Any help is appreciated.

Steve O

Comment: If you provided some sort of visual aid, it may help give us an idea as to what you're getting vs what you want. I'm thinking it's an easy fix that can be taken care of through the report properties.

Comment: Not sure how to provide a visual link. Basically the report renders on 1/2 or 1/3 of the page when the document itself should fill the 8.5x11" page

Comment: Does this illustration describe your problem? : http://i.imgur.com/Y314u.png , or maybe get close. It's hard to guess sometimes, and seeing as how you can't post pictures yet due to reputation, it makes it even harder.